# HUAWEI Push - Error - No permission to send message to these tmIDs

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have sent push notification through  php  code, sometimes the response is success and sometime fail  as  follow:

> {"code":"80300002","msg":"No permission to send message to these
> tmIDs","requestId":"161726525600724073000107"}
>
> {"code":"80000000","msg":"Success","requestId":"161726492809068461000407"}

any help for that , to know what is the problem  ?

Answer (score 3):

1. If HMS Core Push SDK 2.0 is integrated, remove the backslash () from the escape character in the access token and then encode the token using UrlEncode.
2. Check whether the token of the user is the same as that of the app.
3. Check the value of msg type.
   a) If the value is 1 or 3, the message can be sent.
   b) If the value is 2, the message can be sent.
4. Check whether there are errors in the body of the message sent.
5. Test the message push function in AppGallery Connect. If the test is successful, an error occurs when you call the API.
6. In the multi-sender scenario, check the API prototype. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/https-send-api-0000001050986197-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001134031085__section134322259125